# private messages in Symfony

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.8   There are website on it where users can  register. I need to add the possibility of private messages between users. Is there a plugin that will do this? Or maybe some library from zend framework?
p.s Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread : http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29322&start=0

**sfSocialPlugin** may meet your needs.